# NIST Juliet testcases and platform

Tags: c, integer-overflow

I am implementing a tool to discover harmful integer overflows. I tried to use the Juliet test case suite but soon discovered that many of the test cases fail to exhibit security issues on my 64 bit machine, since they assume a 32 bit architecture.

Consider for example this function, taken from CWE680_Integer_Overflow_to_Buffer_Overflow__malloc_fixed_44.c:

```
static void badSink(int data)
{
    {
        size_t i;
        int *intPointer;
        /* POTENTIAL FLAW: if data * sizeof(int) > SIZE_MAX, overflows to a small value
         * so that the for loop doing the initialization causes a buffer overflow */
        intPointer = (int*)malloc(data * sizeof(int));
        for (i = 0; i < (size_t)data; i++)
        {
            intPointer[i] = 0; /* Potentially writes beyond the boundary of intPointer */
        }
        printIntLine(intPointer[0]);
        free(intPointer);
    }
}
```

A high value of data could only overflow on a 32 bit architecture where the size_t argument and int both have a bit width of 32. On my 64 bit machine, int has 32 bit and the malloc argument can thus never overflow.

Hence my question: Does the Juliet suite have word width restrictions? Did something go wrong in the automatic generation of the files? Or is the suite simply wrong or outdated?